# arm ARM1176JZF -- JZF

Tags: linux, arm

I am using a RPi processor.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi

Arm processor have many extension what does ARM1176JZF `JZF` stands here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**J** stands for [Jazelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle) (Java bytecode hardware support).
**Z** stands for [TrustZone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#TrustZone) (security extensions).
**F** stands for [VFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#VFP) (floating-point extensions).

I don't have a source that explicitly states what Z and F stands for, but that information can be deduced from [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_microarchitectures) (the rows of interest are the ones for the ARM11 family).